# Align img right, make page scrollable if window-width is too small

Tags: css, alignment

I have an img which I want to align at the top right corner. If the window is too small, I don't want the image to overlap the text, but make the window scrollable. So I've made a div width max-width: 1000px;.

This is what I have now

```
<div style="z-index: -1; width:100%; position: absolute;">
   <div style="width: auto; min-width: 1000px; display:inline-block;"></div>
   <div style="display:inline-block; float: right;"> 
        <a href="#" id="a_logo_hoek"> 
            <img src="xx.jpg" style="float: right; margin-top:-30px;" /> 
        </a> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: lots of `html` errors in your mark up. It would seem you are missinh a `<` on every `html` tag **EDITED** I see you have now edited it

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
<div style="width: 100%; min-width: 1000px; display:inline-block;">
   <div style="display:inline-block; float: right;"> 
      <a href="#" id="a_logo_hoek"> 
         <img src="xxx.jpg" style="float: right; margin-top:-30px;" /> 
      </a> 
   </div>
</div>
```

Set the `div` that contains your `img` to have a `min-width` of `1000px` and a `width` of `100%`.

Answer (score 0):

- to make window scrollable use `overflow:auto;` in that div which contains all of your page elements.
- to position the image at top right use `position: absolute ; top: 0; right: 0;`
- and now you dont need to use  `min-width: 1000px;`

here is your code::

```
<div style="z-index: -1; width:100%; overflow:auto;">
  <div style="width: auto;display:inline-block;"></div>
  <div style="display:inline-block; position: absolute ; top: 0; right: 0;"> 
    <a href="#" id="a_logo_hoek"> 
        <img src="xx.jpg" style="float: right; margin-top:-30px;" /> 
    </a> 
  </div>
</div>
```